# Flask-User Registration Customization

Tags: python, flask, registration, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I'm currently working on this Flask app (data analysis dashboard) and I'm using Flask-User to handle authorization, registration and login. Regarding customizing Flask-User's registration process, I have a few questions:

1. I don't plan on doing much with e-mail, besides maybe password resetting. Therefore, can I disable e-mail confirmation/account confirmation and have the account already activated/ready after registering so my users don't have to go through this?
2. Only admins will have access to the registration form. They will be the only ones capable of adding new users to the system. (I did that through the `roles_required` decorator) What I want to accomplish is to have role information in the same registration page so it can be saved to my `UserRoles` table when registering a new user. From the documentation, I know how to add new fields to the registration form, that should be present in the `User` or `UserProfile` model. How can I add another form and save fields to my `UserRoles` table in the registration page? I also thought of customizing the `USER_AFTER_REGISTER_ENDPOINT` endpoint to point to a view to add additional info to the user I just registered - that would save me from messing with the `register()` view. However, I don't know how I would pass to this new view the id of the user I've just registered.

If this explanation is still confusing, please, let me know. I will do my best to make it clearer.

Thanks!

Edit: My `User`, `Roles`, and `UserRoles` tables all follow what is outlined in Flask-User's [reference](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-User/data_models.html#user-roles-datamodel).

This question is specific to the Flask-User extension.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from what I could gather you have two tables -
1)UserProfile/User
2)UserRoles

Now I don't know how you have set up your models.py file. It would help if you could shed more light on that.
However let me try and answer to the best of my abilities.

Add a one to many relationship from User to UserRoles so that one user can have many roles(say like editing, updating, deleting etc.)

You can add a one to many relationship using the backref function in SQLAlchemy.
For example -

```
class User(Base):
 __tablename = 'user'
 column1 = Column(Integer,primary_key = true, nullable = false)
 columnUsername = Column(String(20))
```

and you define your userprofile as such

```
class UserRole(Base): 
 __tablename__ = 'userrole'


 userprofileID = Column(Integer,nullable = False,primary_key=true)
 column1role = Column(String(20))
 columnForeignKey = Column(Integer,ForeignKey(user.columnUsername))
 user = relationship("User",backref=backref('userrole'))
#the above line adds a one to many relationship
```

Now when you start adding data from your fields(In flask) you need to first get the user by -

```
user = User(columnUsername = 'someuser')
user1 = User() #create an object of User class
user1.columnUsername = user #what you just defined(can be got from the textbox of entered name)
session.add(user1)
#now get the role you want to add assuming you have defined them already
role1 = session.query(UserRole)filter(UserRole.column1role = 'somePredefinedRole'
role2 = session.query(UserRole)fileter(UserRole.column1role='someOtherrole'

#this adds two user roles to the specific user
user1.userrole.append(role1)
user1.userrole.append(role2)
session.add(user1)
session.commit()
```

That is how I would go about doing it.
I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Point to note is that you don't have to worry about flask but about the ORM you are using(I prefer SQLAlchemy).
If you can master the ORM then you can pretty much hack away at problems like these.
Forgive me if I have misunderstood your question and have ranted for nothing.

Cheers

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering. I'm not sure if I clear was enough, but this question is specific for the Flask-User extension. My UserRoles setup is as outlined [in their reference](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-User/data_models.html#user-roles-datamodel). They also provide Registration templates and view functions in the package. My issue is in adapting their registration templates and functions to my needs (adding these extra fields). I could write my own registration the way you described, but the extension supplied sound business logic for the process I wouldn't want to rewrite.